# RxJava how to handle errors differently at different points in a chain

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have a chain of API calls in RxJava, and when one fails I need to abort the chain and handle the error. But each failure needs to be handled differently. I tried this:

```
netRequestOne()
    .onErrorResumeNext {
        handleErrorOne()
        Single.error(it)
    }
    .flatMap {
        netRequestTwo()
    }
    .onErrorResumeNext {
        handleErrorTwo()
        Single.error(it)
    }
    // more flatMaps with requests...
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
        {
            // deal with success
        },
        {
            // no-op
        }
    )
```

But if a request throws an exception, all of the subsequent `onErrorResumeNext()`'s are called, not just the one tied to that request.

Comment: By returning `Single.error(it)` you are signalling new emitted error from first `onErrorResumeNext`. If you instead return for example dummy `Single.just("")` you should see the requested behavior.

Comment: I want the second request to not even run if the first one fails. I'll edit the question to add that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the requested behavior for example with this:

```kotlin
val requestOne = Single.just("Response 1")
    //.doOnSuccess { throw RuntimeException("Fail second request") } // (1)
    .doOnError {
        println("handleErrorOne")
    }

val requestTwo = Single.just(10)
    //.doOnSuccess { throw RuntimeException("Fail second request") } // (2)
    .doOnError {
        println("handleErrorTwo")
    }

requestOne
    .flatMap { oneResult -> requestTwo.map { twoResult -> Pair(oneResult, twoResult) } }
    .doOnSuccess { responses: Pair<String, Int> ->
        println(responses)
    }
    .flatMap { Single.just("More flatMaps") }
    .subscribe({}, {})
```

You can uncomment `(1)` and/or `(2)` to simulate a fail in the first or second request. In case, both requests end successfully, responses are combined and you do some other processing.